# Is it possible to connect Outlook to webmail server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Currently I have access to my company's exchange server on my iPhone.  I have tried to set up this same connection on my desktop, but every time I try to add the account Outlook throws an error explaining that it cannot connect.

What am I missing here?

If I am able to connect to the exchange server on my phone, why can I not do the same or mimic this type of connection through Outlook.

I have scoured Google intermittently for months trying to solve this, but none of the tips in these guides seem to solve my problem.

I am using Outlook 2010, I am not sure what software version of Exchange Server is being run by my company.

Comment: Its also possible the reason you cannot connect is because the Exchange server doesn't acknowledge you are you.  Talk to your IT staff on the correct way to connect to the exchange server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSync is the component of the Exchange Server that allows you to connect your email to your phone. Where as Outlook uses MAPI, POP3, or IMAP connections to setup your mail profile. The server addresses are different because the way that the protocols work. I am not as adept with MAPI, POP3, and IMAP as I would like to be.

Typically the URL's to connect ActiveSync on a phone and to establish a connection with Outlook are different. You should ask the system administrator what is the proper URLs to create a new mail profile for Outlook 2010. Make sure that the URL is different than the one for ActiveSync. Also you could have the administrator check your mailbox permissions. Although not common they may have given you ActiveSync access, but disabled MAPI, POP3, and IMAP.

In the prior organization I worked at our url for ActiveSync was mobile.domain.com where as to establish an Outlook mail profile it was mail.domain.com.

Comment: Another thing to take into account is whether the company uses Outlook Anywhere or if they require that you use a VPN before you can connect your Outlook profile. It sounds like you are a remote worker so it could be possible that you need to have this VPN connection before Outlook can successfully connect to the Exchange server. Outlook Anywhere on the other hand is a lot like Direct Access where it makes a tunneled connection transparently to connect to the Exchange server.

Comment: Althought I do have VPN access, I am able to login to through OWA without having to connect to it first.  Is there any way to force Outlook to accept the ActiveSync connection and work off that instead of the other 3 protocols?

Comment: Unfortunately Outlook 2010 doesn't have the capability of utilizing the ActiveSync protocol to connect to your mailbox. To access webmail they enable the OWA feature on your mailbox. Outlook 2013 is able to connect to a mailbox through the ActiveSync.

Comment: Lucky me...  I prefer MSO 2010 and have been hesitant to switch to 2013.  I don't think I want to purchase the new suite just to have ActiveSync.  You'd think that they would have a plug-in for this or something.

Comment: I would look into the possibility of using Outlook Anywhere then. That should be compatible with Outlook 2010 so long as the back-end is up to a version that offers it. ActiveSync and OWA were available with Exchange 2003. Outlook Anywhere was introduced in Exchange 2007.